# ui-api within a composite api

Tags: rest-api

I'm looking on an approach to create a ui-api request within a composite api request and its always returning me a response as "The requested resource does not exist".

Following is a simple GET request within a composite API POST request:

```
{
  "allOrNone": false,
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v41.0/ui-api/object-info/Opportunity",
      "referenceId": "opp"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "compositeResponse" : [ {
    "body" : [ {
      "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
      "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
    } ],
    "httpHeaders" : { },
    "httpStatusCode" : 404,
    "referenceId" : "opp"
  } ]
}
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue and has been to resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers
Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI API is not one of the [supported API resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) for the sObject Composite API:

> Composite is supported for the following resources.
>
> - All sObject resources (vXX.X/sobjects/)
> - The Query resource (vXX.X/query/?q=soql)
> - The QueryAll resource (vXX.X/queryAll/?q=soql)
> - The SObject Collections resource (vXX.X/composite/sobjects). Available in API version 43.0 and later.

You'll have to make a separate UI API call before composing your other REST API calls with the Composite resource.

Comment: Thanks David for confirming this.